# Android turn based multiplayer card game

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am looking to develop the multiplayer portion for a cards game (4 players). I have read sp many posts about the ways to do it but many posts are dated back in  2010 so I am wondering if anything has changed.
First of all, I am wondering are there SDK available out there?  I heard about skiller sdk but I need another option just because their service agreement is scary when it comes to paid apps.

If not then I guess my other option would be to do the development using client 0server archeticure. I believe there will be a steep learning curve for the server code. Are their quick-guide tutorials to do this? Are there other options I am missing. It is a cards game and I dont expect more than 5000 users for it for now with probably 100s online at any point
Thanks alot

Comment: If you were doing .NET development, I would suggest using SignalR for the real-time message passing.  If you are cool with a .NET backend, that might be worth looking into.  Not sure if there is something specifically for android.